# ggplot facet_grid labeller function help needed

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I would like to relabel the groups generated by facet_grid, however, all labels do get the same name with my function. I just seem to be blind to the mistake there...

Here is some sample data and my code:

```
data_hrs <- rnorm(513,20,10)
hours <- nrow(data_hrs)
days <- ceiling(hours/24)
days_hours <- days*24

data_hrs[days_hours] <- NA ## padding with NA to reach full no of days
hours <- length(data_hrs)
hours_count <- seq(1:24)
hours_count <- rep(hours_count,days)

count_plot <- seq(1:48) ## 48 values are plotted
count_plot <- rep(count_plot, days/2)

day_count <- NA ## counts the days
for (t in 1:(days/2)){
day_count[((t-1)*48+1):(t*24*2)] <- rep(t,24)
}

mf_labeller <- function(variable, value){
value <- day_count
if (variable == "day_count"){
  value[value == 1] <- "Days 1-2"
  value[value == 2] <- "Days 3-4"
  value[value == 3] <- "Days 5-6"
  value[value == 4] <- "Days 7-8"
  value[value == 5] <- "Days 9-10"
  value[value == 6] <- "Days 11-12"
  value[value == 7] <- "Days 13-14"
  value[value == 8] <- "Days 15-16"
  value[value == 9] <- "Days 17-18"
  value[value == 10] <- "Days 19-20"
  value[value == 11] <- "Days 21-22"
  value[value == 12] <- "Days 23-24"
  value[value == 13] <- "Days 25-26"
  value[value == 14] <- "Days 27-28"
  value[value == 15] <- "Days 29-30"
  }
}

df_plot <- data.frame(day_count, hours_count, count_plot, data_hrs)

print(ggplot(df_plot, aes(x=count_plot, y = data_hrs))+ 
      geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 1, position =     position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
      theme_bw()+
      facet_grid(day_count ~ ., labeller = mf_labeller)+
      scale_x_discrete(limits = c(seq(1:48)), breaks = seq(2,48,2))+
      xlab("Hours")+
      ylab("Movement Intensity")+
      ggtitle("Actigraphy Plot (48 hrs)")+
      theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,18,1,18),"cm"),
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=14),
            axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=14, vjust = 1.2),
            plot.title = element_text(face="bold", size=16, vjust = 1)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, there is the problem with your second line, `hours <- now(data_hrs)`. Namely, `> nrow(data_hrs)
NULL
> typeof(data_hrs)
[1] "double"`

Comment: you might want to use a factor with custom labels

Comment: Oh yes sorry, that was because of the sample data, my real data is a data frame.
I tried custom labels, but hoped that it will not change the order of my plots with a labeller function. Need to automate it and thus cannot change the order afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your labeller function. It's missing a return statement, and ggplot passes the `value` argument to the labeller function, so when you execute `value <- day_count`, you're overwriting the argument that ggplot passed the function with an incorrect vector. The following very slight adjustment works:

```
mf_labeller <- function(variable, value){
  if (variable == "day_count"){
    value[value == 1] <- "Days 1-2"
    value[value == 2] <- "Days 3-4"
    value[value == 3] <- "Days 5-6"
    value[value == 4] <- "Days 7-8"
    value[value == 5] <- "Days 9-10"
    value[value == 6] <- "Days 11-12"
    value[value == 7] <- "Days 13-14"
    value[value == 8] <- "Days 15-16"
    value[value == 9] <- "Days 17-18"
    value[value == 10] <- "Days 19-20"
    value[value == 11] <- "Days 21-22"
    value[value == 12] <- "Days 23-24"
    value[value == 13] <- "Days 25-26"
    value[value == 14] <- "Days 27-28"
    value[value == 15] <- "Days 29-30"
  }
  return(value)
}
```

The result looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNF9c.png).

Comment: Thanks so much! One should stop coding when one is becoming too tired ;-).
Of course, one needs to return the value. However, now I get this message:

`Error in labels[, i] <- labeller(names(label_df)[i], label_df[, i]) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: No clue why it did not work before...now it does, thank you!

Comment: Now something has been changed in ggplot2 and I get a warning message `The labeller API has been updated. Labellers taking variable and value arguments are now deprecated`. And again, I cannot really get my head around where the problem is. Simply writing `mf_labeller <- as_labeller(mf_labeller)` does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChristineBlume See my answer for an up-to-date way.

Answer (score 1):

With the newer versions of `ggplot2`, you firstly have to do a named vector, whose names are the original values of the facetting variable, and whose values are the labels you desire.

For your example, you can do

```
f <- function(n) paste0("Days ", 2*n-1, "-", 2*n)
labels_days <- setNames(sapply(unique(df_plot$day_count), f), unique(df_plot$day_count))
```

to get this named vector:

```
> labels_days
           1            2            3            4            5            6            7 
  "Days 1-2"   "Days 3-4"   "Days 5-6"   "Days 7-8"  "Days 9-10" "Days 11-12" "Days 13-14" 
           8            9           10           11 
"Days 15-16" "Days 17-18" "Days 19-20" "Days 21-22"
```

Then do:

```
ggplot(df_plot, aes(x=count_plot, y = data_hrs))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  facet_grid(day_count ~ ., labeller = labeller(day_count=labels_days))
```

See section **Modifying facet label text** in the [Facets chapter](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/) of the [Cookbook for R graphs](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).